# Problema POO y recursividad

Tags: python, poo

Estoy realizando un curso y en el tramo final enseñan recursividad.

Hay una serie de ejercicios que no logro ni entenderlos (ni con ayuda de otros tutores) ni tampoco ejecutando soluciones que encuentro en este sitio.

Aquí el ejercicio:

Está definida la siguiente clase Alcancia:

```python
class Alcancia:
    def __init__(self, nombre, dinero, alcancia):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.dinero = dinero
        self.siguiente_alcancia = alcancia
```

Cada alcancía tiene un `nombre` que es un **string** que guarda una descripción del tipo de alcancía, un entero `dinero` con la cantidad de dinero almacenado en la alcancía y una alcancía `siguiente_alcancia`, la cuál es la siguiente alcancía de la cuál vas a sacar dinero si se acaba el de la alcancía actual.

Por ejemplo, si tienes las siguientes alcancías:

```python
a1 = Alcancia('Chanchito de greda', 900, None)
a2 = Alcancia('Debajo del Colchón', 100, a1)
```

Entonces si intentas quitar 300 de la alcancía `a2` deberás quitar los `100` que le quedan y luego `200` de la alcancía `a1`.

Notar que la alcancía `a1` no tiene una `siguiente_alcancia` (ya que `siguiente_alcancia = None`). Puedes suponer que nunca se pedirá sacar más dinero del que contiene una alcancía cuya siguiente alcancía sea `None`.

Para este ejercicio deberás definir la función recursiva `sacar_dinero(alcancia, monto)`. La función deberá restar el monto de la alcancía indicada. Si el dinero en la alcancía no alcanza para el monto que se necesita, entonces deberás ir a la siguiente alcancía y sacar el resto. Deberás repetir lo anterior hasta haber restado tanto dinero entre todas las alcancías como el monto indicado.

Nota: el corrector de este ejercicio siempre tendrá la alcancía `a1` con `siguiente_alcancia = None`, la alcancía `a2` con `siguiente_alcancía = a1`, la alcancía `a3` con `siguiente_alcancia = a2` y así.

**Aqui encontre una solución planteada por un usuario** la cual corre adecuadamente y no deberia tener problemas:

```python
class Alcancia:    
    def __init__( self, nombre, dinero, alcancia ):        
        self.nombre = nombre        
        self.dinero = dinero        
        self.siguiente_alcancia = alcancia    
    def sacar_dinero(self, alcancia, monto ):    
        if alcancia.dinero >= monto:        
            alcancia.dinero -= monto
            return True
        elif alcancia.siguiente_alcancia is not None: 
            monto_restante = monto - alcancia.dinero
            alcancia.dinero = 0 
            return alcancia.sacar_dinero( alcancia.siguiente_alcancia, monto_restante )
        else:
            return False
```

Pero cuando lo envio me devuelve que el error:

> *Expected method 'sacar_dinero' to be defined as: def sacar_dinero(alcancia, monto):*

No comprendo como puede resultar un código en donde un método prescinda del `Self` de la Clase o bien intenté realizarlo como una función pero no me permite llamar a otra "alcancia".

¿Alquien tiene una idea?

Comment: Que tal, remueve el parámetro **self** de tu función **sacar_dinero**, eso debería solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Lo intenté, pero me arroja incidente TypeError: Alcancia.sacar_dinero() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Probablemente en algún lugar de tu código estas enviando 3 parámetros a la función, a lo mejor no he entendido bien tu problema, pero sí de **sacar_dinero** se recibe el monto actual y el monto a retirar entonces solo necesita 2 parámetros.

Comment: Toda las soluciones que te han dado asumen que la función `sacar_dinero()` es parte de la implementación de la `alcancia`  pero me imagino que coursera esta esperando que se resuelva como una función independiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parto de la base de que comparto las reflexiones de las otras respuestas sobre los errores conceptuales y de diseño del ejercicio, habiendo formas mucho más simples, legibles y eficientes de implementar esto en Python y que mis propias soluciones no me gustan nada...

Si tomamos al pie de la letra el ejercicio:

> ... deberás definir la **función** recursiva sacar_dinero(alcancia,
> monto)...

dado que dice "funcion" y no "método", yo en mi inocencia asumo que el ejercicio esta bien redactado/traducido y entonces me planteo que lo que pediría seria algo como:

```
class Alcancia:
    def __init__(self, nombre, dinero, alcancia):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.dinero = dinero
        self.siguiente_alcancia = alcancia


def sacar_dinero(alcancia, monto):
    if monto > alcancia.dinero:
        sacar_dinero(alcancia.siguiente_alcancia, monto - alcancia.dinero)
        alcancia.dinero = 0
    else:
        alcancia.dinero -= monto
```

---

```
a1 = Alcancia('Chanchito de greda', 900, None)
a2 = Alcancia('Debajo del Colchón', 100, a1)
a3 = Alcancia('Florero', 50, a2)

sacar_dinero(a3, 200)
print(*(f"{alc.nombre}: {alc.dinero}" for alc in (a3, a2, a1)), sep="\n")
```

La función no tiene "red de seguridad", asumo que no me mienten cuando dicen:

> Puedes suponer que nunca se pedirá sacar más dinero del que contiene
> una alcancía cuya siguiente alcancía sea `None`.

Este seria un planteamiento y una solución medianamente aceptable, aunque existen mejores formas de hacer esto en Python sin usar recursividad y listas enlazadas...

Si eso no funciona y tenemos en cuenta este error:

```
Expected method 'sacar_dinero' to be defined as: def sacar_dinero(alcancia, monto):
```

pues parece que quiere llamar a `sacar_dinero` como un método (de clase o de instancia, vete a saber...) y que tenga los argumentos `alcancia` y `monto` y nada de `self` o `cls`...

Se me ocurren dos aberraciones posibles, la primera es que si el corrector realmente llama al método así (siguiendo el ejemplo anterior):

```
a3.sacar_dinero(200)
```

entonces simplemente podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
class Alcancia:
    def __init__(self, nombre, dinero, alcancia):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.dinero = dinero
        self.siguiente_alcancia = alcancia

    def sacar_dinero(alcancia, monto):
        if monto > alcancia.dinero:
            alcancia.siguiente_alcancia.sacar_dinero(monto - alcancia.dinero)
            alcancia.dinero = 0
        else:
            alcancia.dinero -= monto
```

---

```
a1 = Alcancia('Chanchito de greda', 900, None)
a2 = Alcancia('Debajo del Colchón', 100, a1)
a3 = Alcancia('Florero', 50, a2)

a3.sacar_dinero(200)
print(*(f"{alc.nombre}: {alc.dinero}" for alc in (a3, a2, a1)), sep="\n")
```

`self` es una convención realmente, puedes llamar la parámetro como te de la gana (en la vida "real" no lo hagas por favor...)

Si el corrector en cambio quiere llamar al método de alguna de estas dos formas :

```
a3.sacar_dinero(a3, 200)
Alcancia.sacar_dinero(a3, 200)
```

entonces podemos recurrir a un método estático, que es una aberración conceptual aún mayor...

```
class Alcancia:
    def __init__(self, nombre, dinero, alcancia):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.dinero = dinero
        self.siguiente_alcancia = alcancia

    @staticmethod
    def sacar_dinero(alcancia, monto):
        if monto > alcancia.dinero:
            alcancia.sacar_dinero(alcancia.siguiente_alcancia, monto - alcancia.dinero)
            alcancia.dinero = 0
        else:
            alcancia.dinero -= monto
```

---

```
a1 = Alcancia('Chanchito de greda', 900, None)
a2 = Alcancia('Debajo del Colchón', 100, a1)
a3 = Alcancia('Florero', 50, a2)

Alcancia.sacar_dinero(a3, 200) # ó a3.sacar_dinero(a3, 200)
print(*(f"{alc.nombre}: {alc.dinero}" for alc in (a3, a2, a1)), sep="\n")
```

Comment: Ahi he probado. La respuesta primera que indicaste (la inocente) es la que tomó como correcta. No comprendo porque las demás no resultan validas si lo son.... en fin. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Esto no es la respuesta que espera tu profesor, pero hay errores conceptuales en la formulación del problema, ademas de errores sobre el correcto uso de Python.

Si quieres practicar recursividad, hay ejercicios donde es necesario por la misma definición del problema. No es este el caso, donde todo se puede resolver por iteración.

Es una mala señal el implementar listas enlazadas en Python. No tienes para que hacerlo; Phython maneja listas a la perfección. Python no es C/C++ para que necesites andar persiguiendo punteros.

Un error conceptual es mezclar en una sola clase dos cosas distintas: la cosa y una colección de esas cosas. Es un error; una alcancía no tiene porque saber de otras alcancías.

La forma correcta de organizar objetos es ponerlos dentro de un contenedor o una clase contenedora. Así puedes usar el mismo objeto alcancía en distintos contenedores (listas, diccionarios, etc.)

**Clase Alcancia**

Una alcancía solo tiene un nombre y una cantidad depositada.

La función `sacar_dinero` solo afecta a la misma alcancía.

```
class Alcancia:
    def __init__( self, nombre, dinero):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.dinero = dinero

    def sacar_dinero(self, monto ):
        rebajar = min(monto, self.dinero)
        self.dinero -= rebajar
        return monto - rebajar

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Alcancía {self.nombre}: ${self.dinero}"
```

**Clase Caja**

Una *caja* es una lista ordenada de alcancías. Usas la función `add()` para ir agregando alcancías, y llamas a `sacar_dinero()` cuando necesitas plata. Esta función recorre la lista hasta extraer lo necesario y devuelve la cantidad que faltó para completar el monto requerido.

```
class Caja:
    def __init__(self):
        self.caja = []

    def add(self, alcancia):
        self.caja.append(alcancia)

    def sacar_dinero(self, monto):
        for alcancia in self.caja:
            monto = alcancia.sacar_dinero(monto)
            if monto == 0:
                break
        return monto

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(alcancia) for alcancia in self.caja)
```

**Demo**

```
class Alcancia:
    def __init__( self, nombre, dinero):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.dinero = dinero

    def sacar_dinero(self, monto ):
        rebajar = min(monto, self.dinero)
        self.dinero -= rebajar
        return monto - rebajar

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Alcancía {self.nombre}: ${self.dinero}"

class Caja:
    def __init__(self):
        self.caja = []

    def add(self, alcancia):
        self.caja.append(alcancia)

    def sacar_dinero(self, monto):
        for alcancia in self.caja:
            monto = alcancia.sacar_dinero(monto)
            if monto == 0:
                break
        return monto

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(alcancia) for alcancia in self.caja)

caja = Caja()
caja.add(Alcancia('Chanchito de greda', 900))
caja.add(Alcancia('Debajo del Colchón', 100))

caja.sacar_dinero(100)
print(caja)
caja.sacar_dinero(850)
print(caja)
```

produce

```
Alcancía Chanchito de greda: $800
Alcancía Debajo del Colchón: $100
Alcancía Chanchito de greda: $0
Alcancía Debajo del Colchón: $50

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta. El dilema que me aqueja es que para que lo tomen como "correcto", ya que es la maquina quien da el visto bueno, precisa que def sacar_dinero tenga dos parametros que indica el enunciado del problema (alcancia y dinero). Es mucho mas legible y entendi mejor con tu código pero me devolverá error.

Comment: Entiendo que posiblemente coursera le pide una función independiente y no una implementación de `alcancia`, por cierto bienvenido de vuelta Moe

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo una solución a tu problema:

He añadido una variable `__alcancias` que guardará todas las instacias creadas de la clase y, de esa manera, te será más fácil para identificar la siguiente alcancía. No tendrás que pasársela a la función como argumento.

También he establecido el argumento `alcancia` como opcional para mejorar el código y poder tanto indicar cual es la siguiente alcancía como intuirla en el caso de que no se le pase el argumento.

Respecto a lo de pasarle la alcancía en la función de `sacar_dinero` opino que es innecesario ya que ya estás indicando cuál será la siguiente alcancía en el momento en el que creas la instancia.

```
class Alcancia:
    __alcancias = [None]
    def __init__( self, nombre, dinero, alcancia = None):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.dinero = dinero
        self.siguiente_alcancia = Alcancia.__alcancias[-1] if alcancia is None else alcancia
        Alcancia.__alcancias.append(self)

    def sacar_dinero(self, monto):
        if self.dinero >= monto:
            self.dinero -= monto
            return True
        elif self.siguiente_alcancia is not None:
            monto_restante = monto - self.dinero
            self.dinero = 0
            return self.siguiente_alcancia.sacar_dinero(monto_restante)
        else:
            return False
```

Ejemplo 1:

```
a1 = Alcancia('Chanchito de greda', 900)
a2 = Alcancia('Debajo del Colchón', 100)
a3 = Alcancia('En el banco', 100)
a3.sacar_dinero(300)
print(a1.dinero) # 800
print(a2.dinero) # 0
print(a3.dinero) # 0
```

Ejemplo 2:

```
a1 = Alcancia('Chanchito de greda', 900)
a2 = Alcancia('Debajo del Colchón', 100, a1)
a3 = Alcancia('Debajo del Colchón', 100, a1)
a3.sacar_dinero(300)
print(a1.dinero) # 700
print(a2.dinero) # 100
print(a3.dinero) # 100
```

Comment: Gracias!! Lamentablemente el enunciado me pide que la funcion sacar dinero tenga los dos parametros indicados y he allí mi problema: no comprendo como cumplir con el enunciado y poder hacer funcionar el código.

Comment: @Maximiliano, ya he editado el código. Aunque la función no incluya el argumento `alcancia` tal y como tú pides, he razonado porque no es necesario y considero que el código sería peor y más complicado

Comment: Si @Daniel Sánchez. El codigo es correcto y esta superclaro. Mi situacion es que la web del curso (coursera) pide que tenga esos dos argumentos y no le veo mucho sentido pero sino no me aprueba el ejercicio. Tampoco le veo sentido agregar Alcancia ya que el POO permite trabajar de otra manera como has demostrado.

Comment: Entiendo que posiblemente coursera le pide una función independiente y no una implementación dentro de  `alcancia`